# ORA-12541 TNS :no listener on 1 specific remote database, but not on others

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, tnsnames, tns

Some context:  I'm setting up an environment to run some Ruby code our Lead wrote to connect to some remote Databases. I'm using Win10 and have WSL installed.  I have installed SQL*Plus, docker, and Ruby, and am sure I have installed all the dependent gems (actually at this point I know for a fact its not a ruby problem).  I'm using Docker to use a pre-built image of an Oracle Database, and I have populated it with data.

*Obfuscated company DB information:*

'Broken' DB (TNS no listener)

- Username: W-WORK-DEV
- Password: password
- Host: host1
- Port: 999
- SID: W-WORK-DB.tech.company

'Working' DB (can connect just fine)

- Username: C-OLD-DEV
- Password: password
- Host: host2
- Port: 999
- SID: C-OLD-DB.tech.company

> Please note the names I have provided here are purely for obfuscation, they do not represent anything about age or even config.  They are essentially the same, just different databases on different hosts.  Also note this is a corporate company and would have a lot of base infrastructure for their internal network.

The issue I am having is that with the specific database I am working on, I cannot connect to it.  I connect to the company intranet via a VPN (I work offsite) and have issues connecting to `WORK-DB.tech.company`, though I can connect to `C-OLD-DB.tech.company`.  Methods I have tried to connect with:

- Oracle SQL Developer

I have inputted all the correct jdbc strings and username / password.  **Have even asked other people to attempt to connect (at least 3 others).**  They can all access `C-OLD-DB` as well as `W-WORK-DB`.  When using this method, I get `The network adapter could not establish the connection`.

> Side note:  I'm fairly sure I have connected to the DB just fine in the past, though I can't be certain because I'm fairly new to this team and have only accessed it once, if that.

- SQL*Plus via WSL

I installed SQL*Plus because I think Ruby was accessing it in some capacity when running the script.  I got to the point where the script was able to connect to my local docker Database, but when it tried to connect to the remote database, it would return `TNS: no listener`.   I attempted this using sqlplus as well and got the same error.

> Example:
>
> - sqlplus C-OLD-DEV/password@host2:999/C-OLD-DB.tech.company
>
>   - This command works and connected to the DB jsut fine.
> - sqlplus W-WORK-DEV/password@host1:999/W-WORK-DB.tech.company
>
>   - This command gave me TNS: no listener.

During my research I had found mentions about tnsnames.ora, sqlnet.ora, and listener.ora.  I have found relevant files around the company intranet and attempted to use them in my own personal environment to no avail (one of the sqlnet.ora files actually stopped me from being able to connect to any)  I found mention about a `config/database.yml` file related to ruby, but our code already has the database information set up and I seem to be getting to the same solution as the script when trying to manually connect via sqlplus.

Here are some relevant environment variables I have set up when doing these installs.  I'm thinking that at some point when trying to set up my environment, I messed up some config that changed the way sqldeveloper or sql plus would connect to that database.

> $ echo $ORACLE_HOME: /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/
>
> $ echo $TNS_ADMIN: /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/network/admin
>
> $ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib

I hope I have provided all the information I have come across and have explained clearly what my issue is, if you have any questions feel free to comment about it so I can clear it up.  Thank you for any and all your help.

Comment: I think you get the no listener error if you can't connect to a listener on the port and host that you reference, port 999 and host1 in your example. You could try using ping to see if you can connect to host1.

Comment: But wouldn't that cause other people as well to fail?  I've had several other people successful connect to the database via SQL Developer.

Comment: Ping works fine:

>$ ping host1
PING host1.tech.company (ip.address) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from host1.tech.company (ip.address): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=27.7 ms
64 bytes from host1.tech.company (ip.address): icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=25.9 ms
64 bytes from host1.tech.company (ip.address): icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=26.7 ms
64 bytes from host1.tech.company (ip.address): icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=26.0 ms
^C
--- host1.tech.company ping statistics ---
27 packets transmitted, 27 received, 0% packet loss, time 26018ms

Comment: Could a firewall be blocking port 999 but letting the ping through?

Comment: But its working with other people?  The only thing in that regard I could think of is the VPN i am connecting through, though there are others using the same set up as me with the VPN and they can connect just fine.  

The hosts are different, but they are set up by the same set of DBA admins, so all their infrastructure should be the same, regardless of the ports, so it does not explain why I can connect to 1 DB but not the other.

I have a strong feeling it is probably something to do with my local config, I just don't know what it is.

Comment: I bet it is your tnsnames.ora and/or sqlnet.ora file. Try this command: sqlplus user/password@"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host1)(PORT=999))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=W-WORK-DB.tech.company)))"

Comment: More context for that:  I tried without having any of those files:  i get the result i posted above.  I got a tnsnames.ora file from the internal network on a working machine, same result.  Its only when I add a sqlnet.ora file from the internal network where it fails for every DB: `ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified`

Comment: Here are some possible values for those two files: tnsnames.ora

HOST1.WORLD =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(Host = HOST1)(Port = 999))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = W-WORK-DB.tech.company)
    )
  )
  
sqlnet.ora

names.default_domain = world
name.default_zone = world

Comment: The sqlnet.ora defines the domain. The tnsnames.ora has an entry that relates a name to the host, port, and sid.

Comment: tnsnames defines SERVICE_NAME instead of SID, but I think that should be fine..  This file seems to have TNS definitions for the whole company. ---- sqlnet.ora has: NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (LDAP,TNSNAMES); NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN = tech.company

Comment: `ERROR: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified`  --- when i use the sqlnet.ora for all connections.

Comment: I would take LDAP out of your sqlnet.ora and try it with your tnsnames.ora file.

Comment: Same error.  `ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified`

Comment: The 12154 error means it can't find the name in the file. You should be able to do sqlplus user/password@host1 if host1.tech.company is in the tnsnames.ora file. It would have an entry like host1.tech.company = followed by stuff in parentheses.

Comment: What is the format for more than 1 entry?  I can for sure see the entry in the tnsnames.ora file, its just surrounded by MANY other entires as well (its on line 400) --- W-WORK-DB.tech.company =(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host72-vip)(PORT = 1601)) (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host73-vip)(PORT = 1601)) (LOAD_BALANCE = yes)(FAIL    OVER = ON) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = W-WORK-DB.tech.company) (failover_mode = (type = select)(method = basic)(retries = 180)(delay = 5))))   (host72 / 73 are me just removing the hostname)

Comment: Should be able to connect as user/password@W-WORK-DB if tech.company is the domain in the sqlnet.ora.

Comment: Right, I should.  But currently, with the sqlnet.ora file in place, I get: `ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified` for anything I attempt to connect to.  When I remove that file, I get `ORA-12541 TNS :no listener` on the database I actually care about, but am able to connect to other databases.

Comment: So my problem ended up being a 'firewall/port' issue. In the end i found out that specific port I was connecting to was blocked, but I thought it was only on my system. Turns out the VPN I'm using was the issue blocking that port. Company has a Primary Data Center and a Secondary one, and apparently the SDC VPN was blocking that port from me. I switched to using the PDC VPN and it worked.  

Thank you For your help Bobby

Comment: You are welcome. It makes sense that it was a port issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my problem ended up being a 'firewall/port' issue.  In the end i found out that specific port I was connecting to was blocked, but I thought it was only on my system.  Turns out the VPN I'm using was the issue blocking that port.  Company has a Primary Data Center and a Secondary one, and apparently the SDC VPN was blocking that port from me.  I switched to using the PDC VPN and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the 64 bit jdbc drivers?

Comment: How could I find that?

Comment: Also, I think this is some kind of configuration issue..  I seem to be able to connect to other databases just fine, just not the one i need.